# How do I upload images to the correct path in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, path

I have a website with the following path for images:  domain.com/images

I am using a PHP script in the back-end to upload images to that folder BUT the page that lets me upload images to that path above is located at domain.com/administration/upload.php.

So now when I am using a script to write to domain.com/images this is what I am using:

```
 $newname="/images/".$image_name;
```

For some reason it won't write to that folder and I get no errors and here's the link from where I got the script:

```
 http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/
```

What do I have to do to make it write to that domain.com/images path from domain.com/administration/upload.php?

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish virtual server path from filesystem path.

There are no `/images/` directory on your *disk*
but something like `/home/www/user/public_html/images/`

so, change your code to

```
$newname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/".$image_name;
```

and it should be okay

Comment: Please, check what folder exists and script have permission to write there.

Comment: @alexandertaver, ok will do that right now.  i'll update here.

Comment: You might also want to learn about this PHP function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: @alexandertaver I checked with the hosting company and they said I have permissions that let me upload it.  They are saying it might be a script issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this for the exact path to folder

/* $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will point to your root folder( www ) and after that your website folder name and them images folder name */

$newname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder name/".$image_name;

Comment: Hey Amit! How is this any different than what's posted above?